# Design decision conflict for methods in a class

Tags: design-patterns, polymorphism, overloading

Ok I will try to explain this as much as possible.
I have a class, say MyLib, the methods of which will be used by another class, say Consumer class.
There is a public method called Navigate() in MyLib, which will be used by Consumer. This method sort of provides a level of abstraction for Consumer, as it can provide different types of navigation using just this method. The following code snippet provides the needed code map.

```
// this method will be exposed to the consumer class.
public bool Navigate (NavigationType type)
{ 
    // this method will decide which private _navigateToXyz() method will be called.
    switch (type)
    {
       case x: return _navigateToX();
       case y: return _navigateToY();
       case z: return _navigateToZ(arg1, arg2);
       case a: return _navigateToA(arg3);
    }
}

private bool _navigateToX() { }
private bool _navigateToY() { }
// two or three additional _navigateTo_() without any parameters
private bool _navigateToZ (arg1, arg2) { }
private bool _navigateToA (arg3) { }
```

As shown above, all but two private methods requires some arguments to be passed. So if I follow this approach, then I essentially have to pass those arguments in Navigate() as well - those arguments that none of the other methods have to do anything with.

I am doing this way right now. But I want to know if there is a better approach possible in this situation?

UPDATE : After some more brainstorming, I think that Navigate() method is not that required, since it pretty much just calls an appropriate method based on the passed navigationType. Now, the navigationType being known by the caller of Navigate(), he could himself call the very method required, if those methods are exposed as public. I hope I am clear. So do optional parameters matter at all now? Method overloading makes more sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have multiple public versions of the method.  That will make way more sense to consumers looking at this through intellisense.

Comment: I kind of thought about that..But the "sense to consumers" part is already being handled by NavigationType parameter that is passed to the Navigate() method. Thats the very reason that Navigate() is being provided; to provide a comfortable level of abstraction to Consumer. So there is no use having multiple public versions. I am thinking of optional parameters as of now.

Comment: @HauntedGhost - optional is not a good way to represent sets of parameters that are mutually exclusive.  optional means "you can provide this if you want".  overload means "you need to provide *either* NavigationType or arg1+arg2"

Comment: @RobertLevy - Ok..first of all let me clear that NavigationType (its an enum actually) is what will determine which _navigateTo_() will be called. So it is going to be passed in every Navigate() call. Navigate() will have some sort of switch case that will determine which _navigateTo_() should be called. Hence, arg1 and arg2, though exclusive to _navigateToZ(), are still optional for Navigate(). I hope you got my point. Now what would you recommend? Also point me if I am wrong somewhere in my understanding :)

Comment: @Haunted - from the info you provided, if someone provides arg1 & arg2 then you don't need the enum to disambiguate what the caller wants to have happen (I know this because the private method that takes arg1 & arg2 doesn't take in a NavigationType).  i stand by the recommendation to use overloads and the .NET Framework Design Guidelines will back that up.  optional parameters in APIs are a big no-no because of the way default values get compiled into the *caller*'s code and are not something you can change later.

Comment: @Robert : After your comment, I thought more about it and I think I am leaning towards your stand. Please have a look at the update that I made to the question and tell me if I am thinking right. Basically what I am thinking now is to ditch the Navigate() method altogether, and make the private methods public so that they can be called directly. The navigation type is known to the caller anyways. So I dont think there is any need to have the Navigate() method.

Comment: @Haunted - whether to expose the 2 parameterless methods or to have a method that takes the enum is a case-by-case thing.  could go either way... if you think callers will end up creating their own enums with switch blocks to determine which of your apis to call, then you should just provide the enum for them.  if you think its unlikely for callers to need to do that, the paramterless and clearly named methods are better.  really depends on the specific scenario you intend your api to be used for - either way is ok.  just don't use optional params - those are evil in APIs

Answer (score 0):

Use optional paramters introduced in .NET 4.0

Comment: Yeah..I am thinking of using optional parameters. Earlier I was like I will have to pass null arguments when those parameters are not required. I was not aware of these optional parameters (my bad! :) ). Anyways, I will wait for some more answers/comments, if any. But there doesnt seem to be any other way, considering the constraints that my design has imposed.

Comment: Sure @HauntedGhost. Wait for more answers and then implement the best solution out of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide an overload, or more overloads, but be aware that overloads decrease API descoverability. Every time the consumer of the API needs to "navigate" it has first to decide which overload to call. This can be ok if the overloads make a lot of sense and if the consumer is already familiar with the API.

Another way is to use a class to pass the parameter. In your case NavigationType could be a class that encapsulates all the possible parameter combinations. This class can also have a few constants so that it can be used almost as an enum. Also the class could have overloaded consutrctors or a fluent builder interface to facilitate usage. Also the class could contain some navigation logic or navigation selection logic if appropriate.

Comment: Yeah..in this case, the consumer is going to have to know which method has to be called. Thats why the NavigationType parameter is passed in Navigate() : to instruct Navigate() the type of method to be called.
I dont appreciate the idea of class. I would rather go with overloading.